# Struggling with parameters to Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, arguments, runtime

I've already checked the many good answers here for the exec() pittfalls, and even read this article http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html but found nothing that helps. I feel like I'm on trial-and-error here without getting anywhere.

I have these two (tested and working on the command line) commands I need to run via `.exec()`:

```
find <PATH>* -mtime +180 -exec rm {} \;
find <PATH>* -mtime +1 -gzip -q rm {} \;
```

But no matter how I pass the parameters I always seem to get a different error which doesn't help in telling what is missing. For example: in `-exec` do I need the `{}` separated from the argument? Do I need the closing `\;` in the call to `.exec()` or not?

My last attempt looks something like:

```
rt.exec( new String[]{"find", path+"*", "-mtime", "+180", "-exec rm {}", "\\;"} );
rt.exec( new String[]{"find", path+"*", "-mtime", "+1", "-exec gzip -q {}", "\\;"} );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it will make your life much easier. Also, your examples are using globbing. You'll need a shell process to make your commands work.

Answer (score 1):

Run the script in the command line and if it Works just copy that string and pass it  to getRuntime.exec(string)
Also you should specify which programm will execute the script, i'm guessing in this case should be cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "find "+path+"* -mtime +1 -exec gzip -q {} \\;"});
```

The interpreter `/bin/sh` was needed, and the rest of the command can go as single argument to `.exec()`.